# Is there an atlas of Algebraic Groups and corresponding Coordinate rings?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I was wondering if there was a resource that listed known algebraic groups and their corresponding coordinate rings.

Edit: The previous wording was terrible.

Given an algebraic group $G$, with Borel subgroup $B$ we can form the Flag Variety $G/B$ which is projective. I am hoping for a list of the graded ring $R$ such that $Proj(R)$ corresponds to this Flag Variety.

Comment: This might help http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. For example, there are a lot of abelian varieties -- what should be listed for them? And in what sense SL_2 (3-dimensional group) corresponds to k[x_0,x_1]?

Comment: It is a standard exercise to write down the coordinate ring of $GL_n$ as a hypersurface in affine $n^2+1$-space.  After doing that, every linear algebraic group is a closed subgroup of $GL_n$, usually given by explicit polynomial equations, so this is easily done.  What do you mean by "the projectivizations"?

Comment: @Grigory & Pete, the question was crappy, I have hopefully made it more clear. :/ I apologize for being opaque.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks for the link, an initial exploration has not yielded what I am looking for, but that does not mean it does not exist.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23426/how-to-compute-the-coordinate-ring-of-flag-variety maybe?

Comment: @Grigory Yes I know of the question, and the I know the asker personally. I know how to compute them in simple cases(like those he mentions), I was hoping for resources that list answers.

Comment: @BBischof, I am not sure what the form of the ideal answer you expect will be. Obviously one can "list" such things using Dynkin diagrams (plus a choice of positive weight, corresponding to a projective embedding), since the complete flag variety $G/B$ depends only on the Dynkin diagram of $G$. But presumably you want a list that contains more information. So, you want generators and relations? A homogeneous basis for each such graded ring, together with a rule for multiplication? It's not clear to me yet.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean for $G$ to be a reductive group.  Keep in mind that $G/B$ is equal to $\text{Proj}(R)$ for many different $R$'s, corresponding to different embeddings of $G/B$ into projective space.  The best object to study is the homogeneous coordinate ring (also known as the Cox ring) of $G/B$.  In that case, when $G = SL_n$, the homogeneous coordinate ring is in Miller and Sturmfels' *Combinatorial Commutative Algebra* Chapter 14.  For the general case, some keywords to look for are "standard monomial theory", "straightening laws", and "Littelmann path model".  The homogeneous coordinate ring of a general $G/B$ (or at least $G/P$ for $P$ a maximal parabolic) might be in Lakshmibai and Raghavan's *Standard Monomial Theory: Invariant Theoretic Approach*, but I am not sure.  Regardless, that is a good introduction to the subject and should have a fairly comprehensive list of references for further information.